# Setting up router, some devices can't be reached

Tags: networking, router, nat

I'm making a fedora router and dns. I never did any harder networking, but now I need to do this, however none of router guides I found seems to work for me. I deleted everything and started over few times on simplest configuration, so far without success. This is my simplified network:

```
fedora router and dns
||192.168.122.1 ---  virbr0 --------------- virbr0-guest 192.168.122.x
||10.0.0.53   ----- enp4s0f2 -- tplink ---- tplink-guest 10.0.0.x
||                            10.0.0.1
||192.168.8.53 ----  wlp3s0 ---- wifi  ---- internet
                             192.168.8.1
```

I tried pings on all devices with these results:

- Fedora can ping anything and DNS is working on all devices
- KVMs on *virbr0*, can access internet and ping
  everything
- tplink-guest can ping *fedora* and *wifi*, also can ping internet hosts but can't access them through browser

Here is firewalld and router configuration:

```
[root@fedora ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone 
externalexternal (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: enp4s0f2
sources: 
services: ssh dns dhcp http https
ports: 
protocols: 
masquerade: yes
forward-ports: 
source-ports: 
icmp-blocks: 
rich rules: 

[root@fedora ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone public
public (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: wlp3s0
sources: 
services: ssh mdns dhcpv6-client http kde-connect iscsi-target https
ports: 8140/tcp 8140/udp
protocols: 
masquerade: yes
forward-ports: 
source-ports: 
icmp-blocks: 
rich rules: 

[root@fedora ~]# cat /etc/firewalld/direct.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
<passthrough ipv="ipv4">-t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp4s0f2 -j MASQUERADE -s 10.0.0.0/24</passthrough>
</direct>

[root@fedora network-scripts]# ip route
default via 192.168.8.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static metric 600 
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp4s0f2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.53 metric 100 
192.168.8.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.100 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 


[root@fedora ~]# cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-dns.conf 
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1

[root@fedora ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0f2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:85:a9:18:43:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.53/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global enp4s0f2
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6ef4:35db:3466:842b/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:5d:43:ae:24:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.100/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global wlp3s0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.8.53/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global secondary wlp3s0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9132:115e:2da1:a084/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:eb:66:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:eb:66:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And tplink configuration:

```
IP: 10.0.0.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 10.0.0.53
DNS: 10.0.0.53
```

I need to share internet access, files and servers between virbr0 and tplink, but I'm stuck on it 3rd day. I think this the best aproach from all I've tried, but maybe there is better way. 
So have I done something wrong or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
So I tried learning networking instead of googling, made a few changes and moved closer to desired result. Things I changed:

- Modified routes and firewall
- Disabled DHCP on tplink router and set DHCP on fedora router

  [root@fedora ~]# cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
  option routers 10.0.0.53;
  option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.53;
  subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
      range 10.0.0.110 10.0.0.254;
  }

This made **everything work, but** one thing. **Tplink-guests can't access** virbr0-guests, but they **can ping** them and this time even **traceroute** them.

I also noticed one strange thing when accessing apache virtual hosts. I still get connection refused error, however when I go to host.example it opens http://host.example, but when I go to ssl.example it redirects me to **https**://ssl.example so somehow I get the information about **redirecting to https** from apache. I can't think of anything that might cause it or how should I continue.